# Omega limit set of a dynamical systems is equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

I've stumbled accros an exercise that says.
Consider $x'=f(x),f\in C^1$ in the plane, $\phi(t,x)$ the corresponding dynamical system, defined for $t\in \mathbb{R},x\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose there exists $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\omega(x)=X, \, \forall x\in X$.
Show that $X$ has only equilibrium points, that is $f\vert_X=0$.

At first, I cannot understand this intuitively. For instance, the simple oscillator has only closed orbits and an equilibrium point at $(0,0)$. Doesn't this have the same limit set?

Comment: As stated this seems wrong. Take any standard example with limit circle, like $z'=iz+(1-|z|^2)z$, $z=x_1+ix_2$, where the limit cycle (here unit circle) satisfies the assumption for $X$ but with a non-zero vector field on it.

Comment: The closed orbits of  $x'=y, y'=-x$ do not serve as a counter example?

Comment: They do, if you want it to be completely simple. The question is what in the setup is missing to justify the claim. I have no idea.

Comment: Since the possible forms of compact limit sets are equilibrium points, periodic orbits or unions of equilibrium points and the trajectories connecting them, maybe if we assume that there is no regular point ?